# Webpack dev server custom parameters from command line

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-dev-server, vue-loader

I want to pass custom parameters from command line. Something like this:

```
webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --customparam1=value
```

Exactly what I am trying to achieve is that I am working on a vue-loader application. The application has certain services that fetch data.

I have another application that acts as the api server. We need the application to run in 2 ways (because all members of our team don't have access to the api server)

So that service has 2 ways to get data:

1) If api server is running(for dev team), use http calls to get the data from localhost

2) If api server is not running(for design team), simply use static data already there in services:

```
var someData;
if (customparam1 === "withApi"){
   someData=getData("http://localhost:8081/apiendpoint");
} else {
   someData=[
       {a:b},
       {c:d},
       // more custom array of static data
       .....
   ]
}
```

So this customparam1 is supposed to be passed from webpack-dev-server command line and as per [this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) documentation, no such way exists that I could find(did I miss something?)

How do I do it?

PS: I am on webpack 1.12.1

Answer (score 10):

**Update: 2020 / 2 / 16**

#### 1. webpack^4

If you are using webpack4 or the latest one, using the [environment variables](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/) is very handy!

> The webpack command line environment option --env allows you to pass in as many environment variables as you like. Environment variables will be made accessible in your webpack.config.js. For example, --env.production or --env.NODE_ENV=local (NODE_ENV is conventionally used to define the environment type, see here.)

For example, the command is like:

`env.NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server`

Inside the webpack.config.js, we can define the env variable inside `new webpack.DefinePlugin()` to make it available in the app.

webpack.config.js:(plugin)

```
// pass the env and return the webpack setting
module.exports = env => {  
  console.log(env);

  return {
    ....
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./public/index.pug",
        inject: false
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({ customparam1: JSON.stringify(env.customparam1) })
    ],

        }
      ]
     ....
    }
  };
};
```

#### 2. create-react-app

Check react-create-app [doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-temporary-environment-variables-in-your-shell), the variable will start with `REACT_APP_`

command:
`REACT_APP_CUSTOM_VARIABLE=234 npm run dev`

app:

`console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_CUSTOM_VARIABLE) // 234`

#### 3. old answer

command:

```
webpack-dev-server  --customparam1=value
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

function findPara(param){
    let result = '';
    process.argv.forEach((argv)=>{
        if(argv.indexOf('--' + param) === -1) return;
        result = argv.split('=')[1];
    });
    return  result;
}

const customparam1 = findPara('customparam1');

module.exports = {
   ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 
            customparam1:JSON.stringify(customparam1) 
        })
    ]
};
```

main js file:

```
if(customparam1 === xxx){ ... }
```

Comment: `webpack-dev-server --customparam1=value` does not work, only well-known arguments are allowed.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `--define` option, which takes `var=value` as argument. Webpack will simply replace all the occurrences with the value. For example with the following code:

```
if (ENABLE_API) {
  // Use api
} else {
  // Use static data
}
```

When you run:

```
webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --define ENABLE_API
```

it will result in:

```
if (true) {
  // Use api
} else {
  // Use static data
}
```

You would also need to run it with `--define ENABLE_API=false`, otherwise it will throw an error that `ENABLE_API` is not defined. As it's a simple text replacement, the value you pass will be inserted as is, so if you want a string you'd have to use `'"value"'` (note quotes inside quotes) otherwise it is interpreted as regular JavaScript, but I couldn't get a string to work from the command line.

You can achieve the exact same by using [webpack.DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) (I linked the webpack 2 docs, but it works the same in webpack 1). With that you can have more complex replacements and are also able to use utilities like `JSON.stringify` to create a string version. For instance to overcome the problem with passing a string from the command line, you can use:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  API_TYPE: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_TYPE)
})
```

And run with the environment variable `API_TYPE` set to `withApi`:

```
API_TYPE=withApi webpack-dev-server --inline --hot
```

and every `API_TYPE` will be replaced with the string `'withApi'`, if you don't specify it at all, it will just be undefined.

Comment: This really works! Thanks for the answer. The only issue I find with this is that I am having to shut down browser and start again with the url of local app if I restart webpack server, otherwise it gives 404 error. Do you also face the same issue?

Comment: I verified this on firefox. But on chrome even restarting browser does not work and I keep on getting 404

Answer (score 6):

In `webpack.config.js`, if you [export configuration as a function](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/) (instead of an object) you can easily access the provided options:

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    const customparam1 = argv.customparam1;
    // ...
}
```

[webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/):

> The function will be invoked with two arguments:
>
> - environment [...]
> - An options map (**argv**) [...] (which) describes the options passed to webpack

**Note**:

If you provide:

`webpack-dev-server --customparam1=true --customparam2=42`

```
typeof argv.customparam1  // string
typeof argv.customparam2  // number
```

Answer (score 2):

`webpack-dev-server --customparam1=value` does not work, only well-known arguments are allowed by `webpack-dev-server`.

However, it is possible to pass environmental parameters (not environment variables) into a webpack config, if it is returned as a function.

A command line parameter `--env.param=value`, as in:

```
webpack-dev-server --env.param=value
```

will be available in the `webpack.config.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = env => {
  console.log(env.param)
  return {
    // normal webpack config goes here, as e.g.
    entry: __dirname + "/src/app/index.js",
    output: {
      // ...
    },
    module: {
      // ...
    },
    plugins: [
      // ...
    ] 
    // ...
  }
}
```

Such parameters can obviously be passed into the app using `webpack.DefinePlugin` as outlined above in @AppleJam's answer.

Answer (score -1):

anyway, passing custom parameters is not allowed in webpack-dev-server.

but we can use some existed parameters, like --env --define --open, to pass our own values.

just write:

```
webpack-dev-server --env=someparams
```

then you can use the [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) to read your parameters.

done!